# In big query can we limit the no of rows in group by

Tags: google-bigquery

i have data like this

[image]

if i apply this query i am getting like this .

Query :: SELECT   id, ARRAY_AGG(year) grouped_year FROM yourtable GROUP BY id

[image]

But i want to limit the number of rows in group by like this.for example here its 5.

[image]

is this possible in bigquery to get the output like this.

Comment: you can use `ARRAY_AGG(year LIMIT 5)`.

Comment: but i need other 5 also in next row like above example –

Comment: I'm sorry that I also missed  your requirements. In that case, Tim's answer seems most suitable to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to limit the number of records from each `id` to a maximum of 5:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) - 1 AS rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(year) grouped_year
FROM cte
GROUP BY id, FLOOR(rn / 5);
```

Note that you may use any column you wish from your table to determine which 5 records are retained per `id`.

Comment: but i need other 5 also in next row like above example

Comment: @naveen Sorry, I missed that part of your requirement.  `ROW_NUMBER` may still be used.